# Adding horizontal divs to container, keep in 1 row

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to create a UI to show tasks assigned to projects, this is all working fine.  I'm usually coding non UI stuff, so I am lost, with the last part.

I've a container for the project "tiles" and the project tiles etc populating the container is fine, however, I cant get them to continue horizontally past the RHS of the container, I've overflow-x as scroll, which is fine, but they just start a new line.

This is my CSS

```
   .slane_RHS
            {   
            border:1px solid silver;
            border-radius:0px 5px 0px 0px;
            width:70%;
            margin-top:5px;
            background-color:rgb(240,240,235);
            margin-left:-1px;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            overflow-x:scroll;
            }
    .tile{
            width:100px;
            border:1px solid blue;
            display:inline-block;
            margin-left:5px;
            margin-top:1.5px;
            }
```

That's my issue, I want to be able to scroll to see the tiles past the div end, as they just become hidden when vertical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `white-space:nowrap;` to the parent to prevent the inline-blocks from wrapping to the next line:

http://jsbin.com/kagabopiza/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Perfect, many thanks.  Out of interest, no effort being asked for, I usually do the server side, in the background stuff, and this is all alien to me, apart from a quick stint looking at HTML for peoplesoft documents, is there a good tutorial on this sort of thing?  I've seen a few, like W3, but the monolithic view of things I try to get away from.

Comment: Do you mean just CSS in general? There are a lot of tutorials that do a good job, but none that will cover everything. One key concept is the different `display` properties, which you can learn about [here](http://learnlayout.com/display.html). [This](http://learn.shayhowe.com/) is also a decent overall tutorial.

Comment: And feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was suitable for your question ;-)

Comment: Hi,  yes, I did mean CSS, but away from tables & divs, using in-line blocks, I've just started reading a few, I don't think i'll do much UI again, but good to know.  I couldn't accept your answer for 6mins :)

Comment: I'm personally a huge fan of inline-blocks - I prefer using them in a grid as major layout elements over floats and tables. Compatible with older browsers and easy to work with. Moving forward, though, [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is definitely the preferable layout display option.